# Using PHP to search a MySQL database and return paged results

Tags: php

I've come across a problem but any help would be appreciated.
When I query the database using the results posted from a form, the pagination works initially i.e. for the first 10 records but when I click on the 2 hyperlink of the pagination for the second page of results it loses the `$_POST` variable and returns to the full data set.
What is the best way of keeping these variables available for the second (and further) pages?

The below is my complete php file.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="design.css">
</head>


<body>

<?php
include("header.php");
?>
<center>
<div id="content" class="frm">

<a href='admin.php' style='float:left'>Back!</a>
<h2>Search Result</h2>
<br><br>
<?php

include("../config.inc");
     $find=$_GET['find'];           
           // get page no and set it to page variable, if no page is selected so asign first page bydefualt
             if (isset($_GET["page"])){
                    $page  = $_GET["page"]; 
                } 
                else {
                    $page=1;
                }
                // count all record in this table then divide it on 10 in order to find the last page----- every page has 10 record display
                    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tt where TTT='$find' "; 
                    $rs_result = mysql_query($sql); 
                    $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result); 
                    $total_records = $row[0]; 
                    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / 2);
                    // this line check that page no must be in integer format
                    $page = (int)$page;
                    if ($page > $total_pages) {
                    $page = $total_pages;
                    } // if
                    if ($page < 1) {
                    $page= 1;
                    } // if

                    $start_from = ($page-1) * 2;

$q=mysql_query("select * from tt where TTT='$find' order by ID limit $start_from,2");
$c=mysql_query("select count(*) from tt where TTT='$find'");
echo "<center>".mysql_result($c,0)."Filtered</center>";
echo "<center>";
echo "<table border='2' bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
<tr>
<th>TTT</th>
<th>Enroll Date</th>
<th>Gradution Date</th>
<th>ID</th>
</tr>";

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['TTT']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Enroll_Date']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Graduation_Date']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['ID']."</td>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<center>";

              // paginatio start here 
              if ($page== 1) {
              echo " << < ";
              } else {
             echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=1'><<</a> ";
             $prevpage = $page-1;
               echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$prevpage'><</a> ";
             } // if
             echo " ( Page [$page] of [$total_pages] ) ";

             if ($page == $total_pages) {
             echo " > >> ";
             } else {
              $nextpage = $page+1;
              echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$nextpage'>></a> ";
              $lastpage=$total_pages;
              echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$lastpage'>>></a> ";
              } // if
?>

</div>
</center>

<?php
include("footer.php");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add $find to the link as you do with $page. This is what most sites do on searching.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the filtering criteria along with links to next pages.

```
echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=1&find=$find'><<</a> ";
```

and so on with every other link.